# How to load data for TPU inference in Colab, without using GCP?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

For training models on the colab TPUs, the data needs to be on GCP buckets. However, for small amounts of data, I am wondering if it's possible to directly inference data directly from the local colab enviroment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to load local data into the TPU with Colab currently. You will need to continue using the GCS bucket for any data loading into the TPU.

Answer (score 0):

You can read files with Python:

```
with open(image_path, "rb") as local_file:
  img = local_file.read()
```